# Execvp Hangs when output is too large?

Tags: c, concurrency

So I have a remote shell program. It works fine when the output is not that large but when I take a large output from a command it hangs.

Here is a slice of code. I can confirm args work as expected. So for example if args[0] = "ps" and args=["ps", "-ael" , NULL]. The parent will get stuck on the wait(). The child gets stuck on execvp(). However if args is just ["ps", "-a", NULL], where there is less output it does not get stuck on the wait().

I should note this is what it dit on a Mac. On a Linux system is crashes and says free(): invalid next size (normal).

```
 ...
if (fork() == 0) {
          printf("fork %s\n", "  ");
          close(STDOUT_FILENO);
          close(fds[0]);
          dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
          dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
          dup2(errorPipe[1], STDERR_FILENO);
          close(fds[1]);
          fflush(stdout);

          if(0 < execvp(args[0], args)) {
               perror("execvp failed");
               printf("Command Failed! \n");
          }
      }

      printf("%s\n", "waiting");
      wait(0);
      printf("%s\n", "done waiting");
      char errorMessage[3000];
      read(fds[0], msg, command->messageSize);
      printf("msg %s\n", msg);
       ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The child process is waiting for you to read some of the data before it writes more data. The kernel won't remember all of the data for you, only a limited amount.

You're not reading any data because you're waiting for it to finish. But it won't finish until you read the data.

`free(): invalid next size (normal)` is an entirely different problem - that means you are overwriting some memory that you aren't supposed to.